# ¿Qué eventos puedo encontrar al arrastrar (drag and drop) un elemento?

Tags: html5, drag-and-drop

Al realizar un arrastre o "drag" de un objeto en HTML, ¿Cuales son los eventos con los que me puedo encontrar y que puedo hacer con ellos?

Aquí algunos de ellos:

```js
  var dragged;

  document.addEventListener("drag", function( event ) {
    dragged = event.target;
  }, false);    

  document.addEventListener("dragover", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
  }, false);

  document.addEventListener("drop", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if ( event.target.className == "dropzone" ) {
          event.target.style.background = "";
          dragged.parentNode.removeChild( dragged );
          event.target.appendChild( dragged );
      }
    
  }, false);
```

```css
  #draggable {
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
  }

  .dropzone {
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    background: blueviolet;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="dropzone"> 
  <div id="draggable" draggable="true" ondrag="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null)"> 
    This div is draggable 
  </div> 
</div> 
<div class="dropzone"></div>
<div class="dropzone"></div> 
<div class="dropzone"></div>
```

Comment: Quiero lanzar ciertas preguntas que me he encontrado por la red. No tengo código porque no la he desarrollado yo (Me parece ridículo meter un código fallido para hacerla pasar por una pregunta "válida"). Si se han de borrar o replantear, adelante, sin ningún problema. Simplemente creo que son interesantes para cualquier usuario que se encuentre ante estas dudas.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro hecho, creo que queda bastante comprensible colocando todos los eventos y la pregunta redactada de esta manera.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [dragstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragstart)

El evento `dragstart` se activa cuando el usuario comienza a arrastrar un elemento o selección de texto.

---

### [drag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drag)

El evento `drag` se dispara tras unos pocos cientos de milisegundos cuando el usuario arrastra una selección de elemento o texto.

---

### [dragend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragend)

El evento `dragend` se dispara cuando se finaliza una operación de arrastre (soltando el botón del mouse o presionando la tecla de escape).

---

### [dragover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragover)

El evento `dragover` se activa cuando un elemento o selección de texto se arrastra sobre un destino válido (tras uno pocos cientos de milisegundos).

El evento se dispara en el target(s) de caída.

---

### [dragenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragenter)

El evento `dragenter` se activa cuando un elemento arrastrado o una selección de texto ingresa un destino válido.

---

### [dragleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragleave)

El evento `dragleave` se activa cuando un elemento arrastrado o una selección de texto deja un destino válido.

---

### [drop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drop)

El evento `drop` se activa cuando se suelta un elemento o selección de texto en un destino de entrega válido.

---

### Ejemplo

```js
  var dragged;

  //dragstart
  document.addEventListener("dragstart", function( event ) {
      dragged = event.target;
      event.target.style.opacity = .5;
      //console.log("Has comenzado a arrastrar un objeto. [Evento: dragstart]");
  }, false);
  
  //drag
  document.addEventListener("drag", function( event ) {
      //console.log("Estas arrastrando un objeto. [Evento: drag]");
  }, false);    

  //dragend
  document.addEventListener("dragend", function( event ) {
      event.target.style.opacity = "";
      //console.log("Has terminado de arrastrar un objeto. [Evento: dragend]");
  }, false);

  //dragover
  document.addEventListener("dragover", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      //console.log("Has arrastrado sobre un destino valido. [Evento: dragover]");
  }, false);

  //dragenter
  document.addEventListener("dragenter", function( event ) {
      if ( event.target.className == "dropzone" ) {
          event.target.style.background = "purple";
      }
      //console.log("Has arrastrado e ingresado sobre un destino valido. [Evento: dragenter]");
  }, false);

  //dragleave
  document.addEventListener("dragleave", function( event ) {
      if ( event.target.className == "dropzone" ) {
          event.target.style.background = "";
      }
      //console.log("Has dejado de arrastrar sobre un destino valido. [Evento: dragleave]");
  }, false);

  //drop
  document.addEventListener("drop", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if ( event.target.className == "dropzone" ) {
          event.target.style.background = "";
          dragged.parentNode.removeChild( dragged );
          event.target.appendChild( dragged );
      }       
  }, false);
```

```css
  #draggable {
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
  }

  .dropzone {
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    background: blueviolet;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="dropzone"> 
  <div id="draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null)"> 
    This div is draggable 
  </div> 
</div> 
<div class="dropzone"></div>
<div class="dropzone"></div> 
<div class="dropzone"></div>
```